# Writing better Ruby: How to cast a objects to false or true?

Tags: ruby, code-formatting

In ruby, what is the best/most-elegant way to return a value such as:

```
#method returns true or false if 'do i match' is present in string
def method(str)
  str =~ /do i match/
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code as is?  It returns a truthy value when it matches, and a falsy one otherwise.  When expecting a boolean, you shouldn't be using `== true` or `== false` anyway.

Comment: it returns a 0 or a nil. I think it should return true or false, pretty standard convention at... everywhere? Plus I'm not using == true, things like [statement] if method? are. Seems much better than having to remember if the API I wrote returns arbitray values, then finding what those are, then writing logic such as method?.zero?

Comment: But my point is that in ruby, everything except nil and false is truish (even 0!  even the empty string!) so, as your method stands, `puts "I work!" if method('do i match')` will print "I work!".  There's no need for `.zero?`.

Comment: Ohhhh. Good point I'll consider that, thanks (I'm a nuby at ruby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people would do:

```
def foo
  !!(str=~/do i match/)
end

# or

def foo
  match = str=~/do i match/
  !!match
end
```

The second `!` runs the truthiness test and negates the answer, then the first `!` negates it again to get the initial truthy result.

I rather prefer the more explicit syntax:

```
def foo
  str =~ /do i match/ ? true : false
end
```

This does the truthiness, but to me feels clearer. Do what feels cleanest to you.

Answer (score 4):

I may be a heretic for saying it but I think that they implicit return is beautiful. In this case it evaluates to true or false but I can see how people might think that this is unclear.

You could keep the implicit return and make this instead:

```
str =~ /do i match/ ? true : false
```

Answer (score 2):

A compromise between readability and performance

```
!str.match(/do i match/).nil?
```

Comment: Could you replace the `!` with a `not`?

Comment: Using 'not' in this very particular instance would be OK, but there is a difference in priority between ! and not. Try "puts !true" and "puts not true".